# Pandas list filter not giving output

Tags: pandas, list

I have the following scenario.

I have getting sql.run.resultset which I am converting to list.

which looks like `list_input = [('ABC',), ('XYZ',)]`

Now , I have pandas dataframe , and trying to get matching names for my columns with the list

I tried the below code, but this is not giving me no outpur

`in_list_df = df[df['my col name'].isin(list_input)]`

Is there any other way also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should most likely flatten your list of items:

```
list_input = [('ABC',), ('XYZ',)]
list_input_flat = [x for t in list_input for x in t]

in_list_df = df[df['my col name'].isin(list_input_flat)]
```

Or with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

list_input_flat = list(chain.from_iterable(list_input))
```